# Read MS sharepoint.SharepointListItem using python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I'm trying to parse information from the sharepoint list. I'm using a python package called O365, and i was able to get the list item like this "List Item: [https://company.com/sites/SITE/Lists/listname/number_.000"](https://company.com/sites/SITE/Lists/listname/number_.000%22). but it seems like this item does not have specific attribute to show the content.
it has following attributes:

[image]

[image]

how can i get the detailed information about this list item? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use shareplum in Python:

[SharePlum 0.5.1](https://pypi.org/project/SharePlum/)

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

# get data from configuration
username = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
password = "********"

authcookie = Office365('https://tenant.sharepoint.com', username=username, password=password).GetCookies()

site = Site('https://tenant.sharepoint.com',version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
sp_list = site.List('MyList')
data = sp_list.GetListItems()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. what should the "tenant.sharepoint.com" be? is it a direct url from the site i'm trying to access or something else?  I had a hard time to get the authentication, it always said "forbidden for the url".

Comment: "Tenant.sharepoint.com" is the site url, I'm using the root site in the demo above, it could be also like "Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename". "Tenant" should be replaced by the real tenantname in your side.

Comment: Thank you! Does the authentication needs some sort of approval from our company IT? kept receiving this "forbidden for the url" error. Thanks again!

Comment: The sample above didn't support MFA and need at least read permission for the site url.